# PyCharm 4.5 ReStructuredText Support breaks spaces, newlines, tabs, etc

Tags: python, pycharm, restructuredtext

I've been using PyCharm 4.5 for a week or 2 without problems.  Today I enable the [`ReStructuredText Support`](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7124?pr=) plugin (Which requires `Python ReStructured Text integration` plugin).  Once enabled, it associated with `.rst` files.  However, I can no longer edit `.rst` files in a useful way: If my cursor is at the end of a line of text, it will not allow me to add a newline character (only if cursor is on a line which is already blank and is is preceded by another blank line.

Similarly, all """triple quoted strings""" in python code are treated the same way - I can no longer edit Python files as usefully either!

I've disabled both plugins and restarted PyCharm, but the problem persists within `.py` files.   I see the plugins haven't been updated since 2013 - maybe they're buggy?   In any case, I tried to delete the actual files off my Mac looking in `~/Library/Application Support/Pycharm40` folder, but I don't see it (I think it's built into PyCharm).

How can I get my newline/whitespace keys back?

Answer (score 2):

The `Haxxe` plugin was at fault.  removing it made PyCharm resume working as expected.